# Multi counter on a collection list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my code:

```
return (from x in alumni_corsi
        group x by new { x.FAC_ID } into g
        select new StatCounter
        {
            value = g.First().Dipartimento.AreeDipartimento.ID,
            count = g.Count()
        });
```

in fact, for each `AreeDipartimento`, I return an object with its `ID` and the number of time it appears in the table (`DB` rows).

The problem is that I've extended the `DB`, and now `AreeDipartimento` is linked (`LINQ to SQL`) to `Aree`, which can be 1-n. I mean, `AreeDipartimento.Aree` is a list of `object`.

So, what if I would return the same counter of each `AreeDipartimento.Aree.ID` with the same query?

Comment: Have you tried to use the keyword LET? https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/Bb383976.aspx

Comment: I can use it after group: `let areeDip = g.First().Dipartimento.AreeDipartimento` but than how I "loop" it selecting (select new) each Aree item?

Comment: @markzzz - When you will use `select` it will project you `areeDip` object one by one, so you can say `value = areeDip.Aree.ID`.

Comment: I think you have to put your query inside a loop

Comment: Like this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/190af910-8039-40db-939f-e6144844c57f/how-to-loop-through-a-record-using-linq?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @RahulSingh: I don't have `areeDip.Aree.ID` at that point. I can have `areeDip.Aree.First().ID`

Comment: I also tried `join exp in AreeDipartimento on g.First().FAC_ID equals exp.FAC_ID` after the group (then I select each rows), but it says I cannot use AreeDipartimento there :O

Comment: `.AreeDipartimento.areeDip`? Make sense really? It doesnt works anyway...

Comment: @markzzz - The `count` is not the count of `AreeDipartimento.ID` but the number of groups formed with `FAC_ID`. Thus, even if you extend your object you will still get the same count. Now, I am not sure out of all the `Aree` you want to fetch all the Id's or just the first one.

Comment: Can you write a better/more complete formulation of the last statement that is your question? What do you mean by **same counter**? What do you mean by **same query**?